# How to send/display validation error from NodeJs console to Frontend console

Tags: reactjs, express

I am very new to Express/NodeJS.

I have a question.

How do we send error validation in Express to Frontend console or user interface?

// This is my UserController.js code

```
exports.create = (req, res) => {
    
    let data = req.body;
    Users.create(req.body)
    try {
        res.status(200).send(req.body);
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.response) {
            // If server responded with a status code for a request
            console.log("Data ", error.response.data);
            console.log("Status ", error.response.status);
            console.log("Headers ", error.response.headers);
        } else if (error.request) {
            // Client made a request but response is not received
            console.log("called", error.request);
        } else {
            // Other case
            console.log("Error", error.message);
        }
        // res.status(500).send({message: error.message});
        return res.status(401).send(error.message);
    }
}
```

I tried submit the form from Postman with one missing required input, the data is submitted (not into database) but give error validation in express console, I want that error is displayed in frontend/user console, how we catch that error and displayed as alert/toast or in simple way like console log?
When I submit the form from frontend (disable the frontend validation), it's still send the data (status 200) but give an error in express log.

// This is my AddUser.jsx submit handle

```
const onSubmit = async (data) => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:8000/users", data); // my database.
            toastSuccess("Form is Submitted");
            console.log(response.data);
        }
        catch (error) {
            if (error.response) {
                console.log(error.response.data);
                console.log(error.response.status);
                console.log(error.response.headers);
            } else if (error.request) {
                console.log(error.request);
                toastError("Error Request")
            } else {
                console.log('Error', error.message);
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't show very much from your code, as I can see, you don't validate the request body in your server side to proceed to create the user (register).

I think you have setup a express-js server, so I can help you with a simple post request to register a user and validate the data you send from your client to the backend.

server side

```
app.post("/register", async function(req, res) {
    // get the data from the request body
    const name = req.body.name;
    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;

    const errors = [];

    if(!name.length) {
      errors.push("You must enter a name.");
    }

    if(!email.length) {
      errors.push("You must enter a email address.");
    }

    if(!password.length) {
      errors.push("You must enter a password.");
    }

    // check for errors
    // if we have errors, return a 401 (Unauthorized) status code.
    if(errors.length) {
      return res.status(401).send({ status: 'error', message: 'Registration failed.', errors });
    }

    // register user
    // await RegisterUser(name, email, password);


    // user succesfully registered
    // send a 201 status code (Created) with an additional message.
    res.status(201).send({ status: 'ok', message: 'User registered.' });
});
```

client side

```
const onSubmit = async () => {
    const data = {
      name: 'your name',
      email: 'example@gmail.com',
      password: 'changeme',
    };

    try {
      const response = await axios.post('your_api_url', data);
      console.log(response.data.message);
    }
    catch(error) {
      // check if the status code is 401
      // and if we have an errors property inside error.response.data
      if(error?.response?.data?.status === 401 && error?.response?.data?.errors) {
        // log the errors to console log
        for (const e of error.response.data.errors) {
          console.log(e);
        }

        console.log(error.response.data.message);
        return;
      }

      // if other error occured
      // log a default message with the error
      console.log('Error: Something else is wrong. Error:', error);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! It's working in my code, but I have changed the code a little to adapt my project/code style.